# Query Database with Backbone Collection

Tags: backbone.js

I need to query the database using a backbone collection. I have no idea how to do this. I assume that I need to set a url somewhere, but I don't know where that is.  I apologize that this must be a very basic question, but I took a backbone course on CodeSchool.com and I still don't know where to begin.

This is the code that I have for the collection:

```
var NewCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    //INITIALIZE

    initialize: function(){

        _.bindAll(this); 

        // Bind global events

        global_event_hub.bind('refresh_collection', this.on_request_refresh_collection);

    } 

    // On refresh collection event

    on_request_refresh_collection: function(query_args){

        // This is where I am lost. I do not know how to take the "query_args"

        //   and use them to query the server and refresh the collection <------

    } 

})
```

Comment: I suggest you to read the official Backbone documentation about the Sync method: [link](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is you would define a URL property or function to your Backbone.Collection like so:

```
initialize: function() {
    // Code
},
on_request_refresh_collection: function() {
    // Code
},
url: 'myURL/whateverItIs'
```

OR

```
url: function() {
    return 'moreComplex/' + whateverID + '/orWhatever/' + youWant;
}
```

After your URL function is defined all you would have to do is run a `fetch()` on that collection instance and it will use whatever you set your URL to.

**EDIT ------- Making Collection Queries**

So once you set the URL you can easily make queries using the native `fetch()` method.

`fetch()` takes an option called `data:{}` where you can send to the server your query arguments like so:

```
userCollection.fetch({
    data: {
        queryTerms: arrayOfTerms[],  // Or whatever you want to send
        page: userCollection.page,  // Pagination data
        length: userCollection.length  // How many per page data
        // The above are all just examples. You can make up your own data.properties
    },
    success: function() {
    },
    error: function() {
    }
});
```

Then on your sever end you'd just want to make sure to get the parameters of your request and voila.

Comment: The second option with the url function is working. But i'm not sure about the first one.

Comment: how to send the params as you do in the second option

Comment: So to sum it up, you could use the url.property or url.function() to point the collection where it's supposed to point. Rather than building a new function that takes parameters and such, just use the data:{} option in your collection.fetch() method to pass in whatever query args you want. For the most common types of issues, Backbone has it figured out so take a good look at the docs. They're one of the easiest (and pleasant) documents I've read when it comes to a code library.